# How to dynamically update text/javascript src (jotform javascript embed)

Tags: javascript

I've got a jotform that I want to prepopulate fields.

This code works, but I want to dynamically update the name after the "=".

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://form.jotform.com/jsform/202786957650165?fullName3[first]=Tony">
</script>
```

let's assume I can grab the name from the url, such as https://example.com?Tony using the following

```
var fname = window.location.search.substr(1)
```

my question is how do I get the name added to the JS?

This doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://form.jotform.com/jsform/202786957650165?fullName3[first]="+fname>
</script>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but my best guess is you can't do this with javascript. You need a web page processor to accomplish this ex PHP

Comment: I found a solution that works